# DAX Formula to add the Values in Table1 based on a given criteria

Tags: dax, formula, daxstudio

How can i add the values in a given column in Table1, using a formula in Table2.
I need to add all values that meet the condition in Table1[ColumnWithCondition] and show the result in Table2, based on what date the Value in Table1 is active.

this is what i got so far: =calculate(table1[massure],datebetween(table2[day],table1[StartDate],table1[endDate]))

Thank you in advance for your help

[image: Tables Example in Picture]

Comment: Please add your sample data as copiable text along with expected results. Please mark your old questions as solved.